# Write a custom command with @

Tags: macros, document-classes

I'm trying to make my first LaTeX class in order to make laboratory reports more easily, I decided to redefine `\maketitle` so I can put the information that I need. My goal is to achieve something like this:

[image: Goal]

in order to make this I redefine `\maketitle` this way:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{\large\@author}
  \end{flushright}

  \begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \@title}
  \end{center}
}
```

but I can't add the studentID under the author. So, I want to know how to create a command like `\title` which I can define on the preamble and access its content by using something like `\@title` but with the studentID.

### Edit:

Thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/226564/jairo-a-del-rio I get my problem solved and it ends looking this way.

```
\newcommand{\studentid}[1]{\def\@studentid{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \begin{center}
    \textbf{\@encabezado}
  \end{center}\vspace{0.5em}
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{\large\@author}\\
    {\large \@studentid}
  \end{flushright}
```

That way I can define `\studentid` in the preamble and use it in my `\maketitle` definition.

Comment: Something like `\def\studentID#1{\def\@studentID{#1}}`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do the following:

```
\def\studentID#1{\def\@studentID{#1}}
```

Or, if you want something more LaTeX-fashioned (I'm taking `latex.ltx` as reference), you could do

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\studentID[1]{\gdef\@studentID{#1}}
\def\@studentID{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\studentID given}}
```

This is supposed to trigger a warning when `\studentID` hasn't been initialized.